# Error in foreach loop when number range defined with a macro

Tags: loops, foreach

I am having problems to implement a loop that runs over the months of the year and the days of each month. A simple representative example of my current approach is shown below.

```
\documentclass{article} 

\usepackage{pgffor} 
\usepackage{ifthen}

\newcommand\Ndays[1]{\ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{February}}{28}%
                 {\ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{March}}{31}{30}}}   

\begin{document}

\foreach \m in {February,March,April}
  {
  month:\m \par
  \newcommand\Nd{\Ndays{\m}}
  ndays: \Nd \par
  \foreach \n in {1,...,31}
    {
    day:\n \par
    }
  }
\end{document}
```

Evidently, each month has a different number of days, so I decided to define a dictionary associating each month with the number of days through the "Ndays" macro. Now, I need to include the correct number of days for each month in the example above. If I naively substitute "31" by "\Nd" in the inner loop, an error is found when I compile this code with pdflatex:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \equal 
                  {\m }{February}
l.23   }
```

I played around with different macro definitions and \expandafter-s, without success. Moreover, if I define the macro as:

```
\newcommand\Nd{28}
```

the naive substitution does not raise errors. Is there any simple solution and explanation to this?

Answer (score 2):

The obvious glitch (at least for who has some experience in macro expansion) is that `\Nd` does not expand to the number of days, but to the set of instruction for *printing* the number of days.

The following macros associate days to months (also taking care of leap years) in an expandable way.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\printmonths}{O{\c_sys_year_int}m}
 {% #1 is an optional year
  % #2 is a comma separated list of months
  \clist_map_inline:nn { #2 }
   {
    \manual_print_month:nn { #1 } { ##1 }
   }
 }
\cs_new_protected:Nn \manual_print_month:nn
 {
  \par
  Month:~#2 \par
  Ndays:~\manual_print_days:nn { #1 } { #2 } \par
  \int_step_inline:nnnn { 1 } { 1 } { \manual_print_days:nn { #1 } { #2 } }
   {
    day:~##1 \par
   }
 }

\cs_new:Nn \manual_print_days:nn
 {
  \str_case:nn { #2 }
   {
    {January}{31}
    {February}{\manual_february:n { #1 }}
    {March}{31}
    {April}{30}
    {May}{31}
    {June}{30}
    {July}{31}
    {August}{31}
    {September}{30}
    {October}{31}
    {November}{30}
    {December}{31}
   }
 }

\cs_new:Nn \manual_february:n
 {
  \bool_if:nTF
   {
    \int_compare_p:n { \int_mod:nn { #1 } { 4 } != 0 }
    ||
    (
     \int_compare_p:n { \int_mod:nn { #1 } { 100 } = 0 }
     &&
     \int_compare_p:n { \int_mod:nn { #1 } { 400 } != 0 }
    )
   }
   { 28 } { 29 }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\begin{multicols}{3}

\printmonths[2100]{February,March,April}

\end{multicols}

\end{document}
```

Apart from the complication for February, the macros are straightforward: we map the argument as a comma separated list. For each item the function `\manual_print_month:nn` is executed, which steps from 1 to the number of days and does the printing.

[image]

You can check that the output for

```
\printmonths[2100]{February,March,April}
```

is as follows (no leap year)

[image]

A possibly more efficient version of `\manual_february:n` with lazy evaluation of conditionals:

```
\cs_new:Nn \manual_february:n
 {
  \bool_lazy_or:nnTF
   {
    \int_compare_p:n { \int_mod:nn { #1 } { 4 } != 0 }
   }
   {
    \bool_lazy_and_p:nn
     {
      \int_compare_p:n { \int_mod:nn { #1 } { 100 } = 0 }
     }
     {
      \int_compare_p:n { \int_mod:nn { #1 } { 400 } != 0 }
     }
   }
   { 28 } { 29 }
 }
```

Comment: @UlrichDiez Still three comparisons. Maybe some nanoseconds faster, though. `;-)` Let's blame pope Gregory XIII. `:-)` Maybe the team can provide an expandable function taking an integer as argument that returns 1 if the integer corresponds to a leap year and 0 otherwise.

Comment: How about checking divisibility by 4, 16 and 25 instead of 4, 100 and 400? Not divisible by 4 -> Not a leap year. Divisible by 4 and divisible by 16 -> A leap year. Divisible by 4 and not divisible by 16 and divisible by 25 -> Not a leap year.  Divisible by 4 and not divisible by 16 and not divisible by 25 -> A leap year. (I hope I got it right...)

Comment: @UlrichDiez I changed the implementation with a boolean expression, which should be more efficient

Answer (score 2):

You can try this. Exploiting (for once) the fact that `\foreach` works in a group hence LaTeX does not complain with the `\newcommand`. <strike>Hence</strike>Else one would use `\renewcommand` and an initial `\newcommand\foo{}`.

```
\documentclass{article} 

\usepackage{pgffor} 
\usepackage{ifthen}

\newcommand\Ndays[1]{\ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{February}}
                 {\newcommand\Nd{28}}%
                 {\ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{March}}
                     {\newcommand\Nd{31}}%
                     {\newcommand\Nd{30}}}}   

\begin{document}

\foreach \m in {February,March,April}
  {
  month:\m \par
  \Ndays{\m}%
  ndays: \Nd \par
  \foreach \n in {1,...,\Nd}
    {
    day:\n \par
    }
  }
\end{document}
```